# Is sending token authentication information via cookie headers secure?

Tags: django, reactjs, websocket, token, django-channels

0

i am by no means a security engineer , and i have barely started my journey as a web developer. Im utilizing a python package known as django for my backend , react.js for my front end . Recently i have incorporated django-channels , which is a package that gives me the ability to use websockets in my project. Since i have decoupled my front and backends , the basis of authentication im using is via tokens (will look into using jwt) .

The issue is that with javascript , it is not possible to send authentication headers via websocket connection (or so im told) , therefore a lot of people are using cookies to send this authentication token instead. Heres an example snippet of how i am sending the token from my front end:

```
const path = wsStart + 'localhost:8000'+ loc.pathname
document.cookie = 'authorization=' + token + ';' 
this.socketRef = new WebSocket(path)
```

doing this allows me to then extract out the token information through utilizing a customized middleware on my backend .

```
import re
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.db import close_old_connections

@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(token_key):
    try:
        return Token.objects.get(key=token_key).user
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()


class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    see:
    https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html#custom-authentication
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        return TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance(scope, self)


class TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance:
    def __init__(self, scope, middleware):
        self.middleware = middleware
        self.scope = dict(scope)
        self.inner = self.middleware.inner

    async def __call__(self, receive, send):
        close_old_connections()
        headers = dict(self.scope["headers"])
        print(headers[b"cookie"])
        if b"authorization" in headers[b"cookie"]:
            print('still good here')
            cookies = headers[b"cookie"].decode()
            token_key = re.search("authorization=(.*)(; )?", cookies).group(1)
            if token_key:
                self.scope["user"] = await get_user(token_key)

        inner = self.inner(self.scope)
        return await inner(receive, send) 


TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

However this has raised some form of security red flags (or so im told) .

Therefore i wish to extend this questions to the security veterans out there :

1. Is this methodology of sending token authentication information via cookie headers safe?
2. Is my implementation of this method safe?
3. Is there a way to secure this even further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you are using a HTTPS (WSS) websocket connection then mostly.
2. yes it looks oke
3. Yes there is a better way.

Create a regular HTTP endpoint (on this domain name) were you can set a (normal) django session cookie, this would normaly be your django login endpoint. This will set a cookie that is HTTPONLY (aka not readable from javascript). This is important so that any other js code you might use on your page cant read this value and steal it.

Then you can use the https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/sessions.html.

Note when running in proudction (with HTTPs only) you should set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True` in you django settings as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input , i am using a token based authentication with DRF, my front and backend are totally decoupled , is it possible to still do what u have suggested ?

Comment: if you are using token based auth then you can either add it as a `query param` in the url `?token=....` and read that from the scope in your consume. Or you can send a frame `{action: "autheticate", token: ""}` when you get this frame you check the token and authenticate the consume (change a flag from false to true). if you get any other messages before you get the authenticate you close the connection. But all of these expose the secret to JS so not much better than added a header.

Comment: if you go with the header I would just add a regular `Authorization: Token ...` this should be simpler to parse more normal. Since your using DRF token based authentication I would try to send the same header as you do there.

Comment: if you are already using DRF I can suggest you look at using https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework this framework gives you a DRF like interface for writing consumers (it also provides some auth handling)  see this blog article for some more info: https://lostmoa.com/blog/DjangoChannelsRestFramework/